# Draw audio data captured in a main view

Tags: android, view, draw, audiorecord

I am trying to draw audio data captured in a main view like oscilloscope.
I am using AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener()
but my program draw only one time.

the program calls AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() continuously
but it doesnot draw any more after it draw audio data only one time;

I want to draw it continuously.
please help me. I leave a source code

Main Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnTime  = null;
    Button btnVolt  = null;
    Button btnUp    = null;
    Button btnDown  = null;

    int nScreenX;
    int nScreenY;
    int nWRatio = 7;
    int nHRatio = 12;

    int nScopeX;
    int nScopeY;

    ImageView   drawingImageView;
    Canvas      scopeCanvas;
    Paint scopePaint = new Paint();

    AudioRecord audioRecord = null;
    static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    short[] buffer = new short[44100];

    int nTimeDiv = 100;                        // unit : 10us/Div
    static final int nResolution = 200;         // Screen Resolution
    int nImgBuffPos = 0;
    short[] imgBuff = new short[nResolution];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        nScreenX = size.x;
        nScreenY = size.y;

        initiateButton();
        initiateImageview();
        initiateAudioCapture();
    }

    private void initiateButton() {
        btnTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
        btnVolt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_volt);
        btnUp   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_up);
        btnDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_down);

        // 버튼 폭 설정
        btnTime.setWidth(nScreenX/nWRatio);
        btnVolt.setWidth(nScreenX / nWRatio);
        btnUp.setWidth(nScreenX/nWRatio);
        btnDown.setWidth(nScreenX / nWRatio);

        // 버튼 높이 설정
        btnTime.setHeight(nScreenY / nHRatio);
        btnVolt.setHeight(nScreenY / nHRatio);
        btnUp.setHeight(nScreenY/nHRatio);
        btnDown.setHeight(nScreenY / nHRatio);

        // 버튼 X 좌표 설정
        btnTime.setX(0);
        btnVolt.setX(0);
        btnUp.setX(0);
        btnDown.setX(0);

        // 버튼 Y 좌표 설정
        btnTime.setY(0);
        btnVolt.setY(nScreenY/(nHRatio-4));
        btnUp.setY(nScreenY*2/(nHRatio-4));
        btnDown.setY(nScreenY*3/(nHRatio-4));

        nScopeX = nScreenX - nScreenX/nWRatio;
        nScopeY = nScreenY - nScreenY/nHRatio;
    }

    private void initiateImageview() {
        drawingImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.DrawingImageView);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) nScopeX, nScopeY, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        drawingImageView.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) drawingImageView.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = nScreenX/nWRatio;
        params.topMargin = 0;
        drawingImageView.setLayoutParams(params);

        scopeCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        backgroudGrid();
    }

    private void backgroudGrid() {
        scopePaint.setColor(Color.rgb(150, 150, 150));
        scopePaint.setStrokeWidth(6);

        for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
            if(i != 4 && i < 8) {
                scopeCanvas.drawLine(0, nScopeY * i / 8, nScopeX, nScopeY * i / 8, scopePaint);
            }
            if(i != 5) {
                scopeCanvas.drawLine(nScopeX * i / 10, 0, nScopeX * i / 10, nScopeY, scopePaint);
            }
        }

        scopePaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        scopePaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        // set Outline
        scopeCanvas.drawLine(0, nScopeY/2, nScopeX, nScopeY/2, scopePaint);
        scopeCanvas.drawLine(nScopeX/2, 0, nScopeX/2, nScopeY, scopePaint);
        scopeCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, nScopeY, scopePaint);
        scopeCanvas.drawLine(nScopeX, nScopeY, 0, nScopeY, scopePaint);
        scopeCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, nScopeX, 0, scopePaint);
        scopeCanvas.drawLine(nScopeX, 0, nScopeX, nScopeY, scopePaint);
    }

    private void initiateAudioCapture() {
        int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                min);
        audioRecord.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(updateListener);
        audioRecord.setPositionNotificationPeriod(200);
        audioRecord.startRecording();
    }

    public void drawScope() {
        int sx=0, ex=0, sy=0, ey=0;
        if(scopeCanvas == null)
            return;

        scopeCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        backgroudGrid();

        scopePaint.setColor(0xff00ffff);
        scopePaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        for(int i=0; i<nResolution-1; i++) {
            sx = scopeCanvas.getWidth()/200*i;
            ex = scopeCanvas.getWidth()/200*(i+1);
            sy = scopeCanvas.getHeight()/2 + imgBuff[i];
            ey = scopeCanvas.getHeight()/2 + imgBuff[i+1];
            scopeCanvas.drawLine(sx, sy, ex, ey, scopePaint);
        }
    }

    private AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener updateListener = new AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() {
        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder) {
            int len = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            float rate = ((float) SAMPLE_RATE)/nResolution/100;

            int pos=0;
            for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                pos = (int)(i*rate);
                if(pos < len) {
                    imgBuff[nImgBuffPos++] = buffer[pos];
                    if (nImgBuffPos >= nResolution) {
                        drawScope();
                        nImgBuffPos = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder){}
    };

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TIME"
        android:id="@+id/button_time"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VOLT"
        android:id="@+id/button_volt"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UP"
        android:id="@+id/button_up"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DOWN"
        android:id="@+id/button_down"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DrawingImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.oscilloscope" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple troubles with your project.

First of all: it does not draw continuously because you are repainting the bitmap in *drawScope()*, but never inform a *ImageView* that it's content has been changed and needs to be repainted. To achieve that, in the end of *drawScope()* add:

```
drawingImageView.invalidate();
```

After that you will not see good repainting again, because *onPeriodicNotification()* calls are performed too fast. It is not able to complete previous repaints while new notifications appears. You may want to increase notification period. To do that you need to increase input buffer enough. Better not to use it at minimum size:

```
private void initiateAudioCapture() {
    int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    if (min < 16384) min = 16384;
    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            min);
    audioRecord.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(updateListener);
    audioRecord.setPositionNotificationPeriod(4000);
    audioRecord.startRecording();
}
```

Now, depending on processing speed of your device, you can see a changing image.

I suggest you to try another approach:
1) Instead of repainting a bitmap and drawing it on ImageView, create a custom View, and paint whatever you wont inside it's *onDraw()* method.
2) Give up to use RecordPositionUpdateListener, instead of that use a timer to periodical call the update. So, if your repainting will be delayed, some input data will be lost, but it will be ok.

Another approach it is to collect recorded data in separated thread.